# List all bookmarks added with \hypertarget for named destinations

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links, bookmarks, hypertarget

I add bookmarks to all sections in my project in the following way:

```
\section{Introduction}
\hypertarget{intro}{}

Some text.
```

I use these bookmarks later in URL links `https://example.com/my-document.pdf#intro`.

Every time I create an URL referring to a certain section, I need to go back to my LaTeX project and look up the bookmark name as I have too many of them. I would like to have a list of all my bookmarks (ideally juxtaposed with the section names they mark).

I know that the list of all bookmarks can be generated with [pdfinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890799/getting-the-name-of-a-named-destination-with-poppler) on the command line. However, along with the bookmarks I need, I get all kinds of other bookmarks added by LaTeX and irrelevant for me:

```
   1 [ XYZ   57  785 null      ] "Doc-Start"
   1 [ XYZ   56  823 null      ] "page.1"
   2 [ XYZ   57  711 null      ] "section.1"
   3 [ XYZ   57  751 null      ] "intro"
   5 [ XYZ   57  666 null      ] "lstlisting.-1"
   5 [ XYZ  104  668 null      ] "lstnumber.-1.1"
   6 [ XYZ   57  785 null      ] "subsection.1.1"
```

So is it possible to generate a list of bookmarks created by me with `\hypertarget`? I will be happy with any: the command line solution or a LaTeX macro.

Answer (score 0):

I tried tinkering around myself and came up with some **dirty** but working solution thanks to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525586/link-map-from-referenced-theorems-in-my-document) and [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label). I wish I could come up with a better one but need more experience. Still hope that somebody might offer a more elegant solution.

My dirty solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Corrects issues with compatibility of XeLaTeX
% and hyperref to create bookmarks
\special{dvipdfmx:config C 0x0010}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newfloat}% for listof
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
    % temp code for list of bookmarks
    \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=bkmrk]{bookmark}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
    \renewcommand*{\hypertarget}[2]{
      \addcontentsline{bkmrk}{bookmark}{\currentname \qquad | \qquad #1}%
    }
    \makeatother
    \AtBeginDocument{\listofbookmarks}
    % end of temp code
%\end{comment}


\begin{document}


\newpage
\section{First Section}
\hypertarget{first}{}

\newpage
\section{Second Section}
\hypertarget{second}{}

\newpage
\section{Third Section}
\hypertarget{third}{}

\end{document}
```

It gives me this:

[image]

Just before compiling my final PDF, I do the following:

- Uncomment the code for list of bookmarks
- Compile the PDF to generate the list of bookmarks
- Copy the bookmarks into Excel (this step requires a lot of text editing)
- Comment out the code for list of bookmarks

Then I compile the PDF for publishing.